# Disabling unnecessary Apache modules for simplicity and performance

Tags: performance, apache2, best-practices, maintenance

I noticed that my simple LAMP application does not need most of the default modules the [official Docker PHP-Apache image](https://github.com/docker-library/php) bundles by default:

```
a2dismod -f access_compat auth_basic authn_core authn_file authz_host authz_user autoindex negotiation setenvif status
```

Most of these are core modules. I tested my website, and it seems to work fine without them. Is this considered a good practice? E.g. will this positively impact the performance? I imagine that memory footprint and CPU usage could be reduced, although the benefits may be minimal or difficult to notice. It may also be good for security?

Comment: The fact that they are modules indeed means they can disabled when you don’t need the functionality they provide. That offers the benefits you describe. Not using mod_php offers even more benefits in many cases

Comment: @HBruijn I found my tests surprising. In my simple website, using mod_php (vs nginx) was better for performance and scalability, it could handle more jmeter requests. Apache's mod_php integrates PHP directly into the Apache server, allowing for potentially faster response times for each request since there's less overhead in communicating between the server and PHP. I know Nginx with PHP-FPM should offer better performance in high-concurrency scenarios, but I could not reproduce it using official Docker images. (Note: I did not test handling requests for static files)